# Problem accessing value of array after passing via segue in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm passing an Array via a segue and then trying to use the value to set a delay for a timer. Although the values of the Array can be displayed in ViewDidLoad, when I try to access from any other function it appears empty and I just can't work out what is happening. I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but I'm stuck and would really appreciate any advice please

I've displayed the count and values of the Array in Viewdidload which is fine, however when I try to access from any function, they do not display. I've copied code that does not work.
Hopefully to clarify - I have 2 view controllers - the initial one is selectionViewController.swift and the other is viewController.swift, both created in a storyboard with a 'show' segue leading to viewController.swift with identifier sendValues. Originally viewController storyboard was shown initially, then I added selectionViewController - I dragged the arrow in the storyBoard to display this one first.

I've copied the relevant pieces of code below: The code in class selectionViewController sending the values to viewController is:

```
class SelectionViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {



var colourArray = [String]()

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendValues", sender: self)

}

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "sendValues" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController

        vc.colourArray = colourArray


    }
}

//View Controller Class

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {



    var colourArray: [String]?
    var passedArrayCount : Int?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        passedArrayCount = colourArray!.count
        print("count is \(passedArrayCount)")

// the Array values and count display here
     }

  @IBAction func btnTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(passedArrayCount)
// Array count now displays 0
     }
}
```

I've checked the rest of the class and the values are not being reset anywhere, so I don't understand why the values are being passed successfully as shown in Viewdidload, but not after the function

Comment: This class you posted indeed seems fine... So one possible cause could be that you have 2 different instances of the same ViewController. Maybe you can share the code for "I'm passing an Array via a segue" ?

Comment: Thanks - the code I'm using to pass is :     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   
        if segue.identifier == "sendValues" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.colourArray = colourArray
        }
        
     I am getting this error message after the viewdidload method -    
     
   41.867868-0400 Football Agility[16474:1094988] Warning: Attempt to present <Football_Agility.ViewController: 0x7fb528413f60> on <Football_Agility.SelectionViewController: 0x7fb52870d200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: What you guess is right. It depends how you presented the ViewController? from a storyboard? or do it by yourself in  the SelectionViewController class?

Comment: The warning you get implies that the specific ViewController instance cannot be presented. But you do see that Timer button that you press to invoke btnTimer(), which means you are probably seeing a different instance. In order to help I'd need a broader picture, the storyboard and the relevant code inside SelectionViewController. (You could edit your original question)

Comment: well, I quickly recreated this situation and it works just fine. The only other suspect I had is that you have "sendValues" segue connected to the "submit" button in addition to programmatic invocation you have, which would lead to double execution of the segue ( add some print into your 'prepare' method ). However, in such case the error is not "...whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". Anyway, I'd focus on solving the "Attempt to present <Football_Agility.ViewController> on <Football_Agility.SelectionViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var colourArray: [String] = []
var passedArrayCount : Int?

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        passedArrayCount = colourArray!.count
        print("count is \(passedArrayCount)")

        // the Array values and count display here
    }

    @IBAction func btnTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(passedArrayCount)
        // Array count now displays 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I’ve tried that and it still is not working. It is very odd. All I can think is it is to do with the error message above about the view not being in the window hierarchy, which I’ve tried to find a solutions for, but just don’t understand why it is appearing.

Comment: That would be an attempt to solve a symptom rather than finding the real root cause. Moving out variables that by design belong to "ViewController" class has many undesired implications..